# Program Exits Immediately after having no such element found exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am developing a scraper in python 2.7 using selenium. The main issue that I am facing is that my program terminates immediately after having no such element found exception.
I have tried several solutions suggested to me but nothing works. Like use try catch etc.
here is the code that I have tried.

```
def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
    try:
        webdriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True
```

I want the program to resume even if the element doesn't exists.
Can anyone suggest a solution how to do this?
I have tried many other things but nothing works.

Error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "bot2.py", line 22, in <module>

    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 295, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 756, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 238, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="react-root"]/section/usama"}
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

Comment: have you some error messages? can you share them with us?

Comment: It is too long to add in comments so I have edited it in question

Comment: that's exactly what you need to do. commenting is no good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid `try ... catch` constructions as much as possible.

Use a more convenient method :

```
def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
    elnts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
    return len(elnts) > 0
```

Notice the usage of `find_elements_by_xpath` instead of `find_element_by_xpath`, which returns a list of elements corresponding to the XPath expression. The list is empty if no element is found.